# How do you change the number of the glossed example in linguex?

Tags: numbering, linguistics, examples, qtree, linguex

I minimally use the following packages:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\qtreecenterfalse
\item [(2)]\Tree [.BeP \phantom{DP} [ Be [.SC 
\qroof {this task}.NP  
\qroof{ very important}.AP ] ] ] 
\end{enumerate}

\exig. Veoma je vazan taj zadatak.\\
 begin very be{\sc.pres.3sg} 
important this task\\
'This task is very important.'

\end{document}
```

For instance, if the example in the given format is following a numbered syntactic tree it will not continue the number subsequent to the one given to the tree but it continues the number of the last entered example in the document (the same holds if I change the command of the glossed example, i.e. if I use  `\ex.` or `\exi.` instead of `\exig.`). Any suggestions how to fix the example either manually or otherwise so that it follows the number of the numbered item that immediately precedes it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead post a complete, minimal compilable document that shows what you are doing and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons the numbers are different is because you are embedding the tree in an `enumerate` environment, which uses its own counter (and you specified the number in the `\item` command which simply makes a text label, and so isn't even a number.

Simply embed your tree in an `\ex.` and it will number along with the other examples.

Unrelated, but `qtree` is a very old package, and you might be better off using `tikz-qtree` or (even better) `forest` for trees.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\ex.
\qtreecenterfalse
\Tree [.BeP \phantom{DP} [ Be [.SC 
\qroof {this task}.NP  
\qroof{ very important}.AP ] ] ] 


\exig. Veoma je vazan taj zadatak.\\
 begin very be{\sc.pres.3sg} 
important this task\\
'This task is very important.'

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]